# SQL Get Distinct ID but with newest date

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2005

Hii I wanted to get distinct FireUPRNs but with the newest date (FRADate).

Issue:

I keep getting the error -

```
*Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string.
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.*
```

Code:

```
SELECT *

FROM TblFire 
inner join (
SELECT Max(FRADate) as FireDateID, 
FRADate 
FROM TblFire GROUP BY FRADate)
FireDateID
ON FireDateID.FireDateID = TblFire.FireUPRN
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Added (2005 in this case).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieving the last record in each group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group)

Answer (score 1):

Your query is quite confused, taking the max of a date column and calling it an id.  Without a table layout, I think this is what you actually want:

```
SELECT f.*
FROM TblFire f INNER JOIN
     (SELECT FireUPRN, MAX(FRADate) as FRADate
      FROM TblFire
      GROUP BY FireUPRN
     ) fmax
     ON f.FRADate = fmax.FRADate and f.FireUPRN and fmax.FireUPRN;
```

Comment: When I run SELECT DISTINCT FireUPRN
FROM TblFire f INNER JOIN
     (SELECT Max(FRADate) as FRADateID, FRADate 
      FROM TblFire
      GROUP BY FRADate
     ) fmax
     ON f.FireUPRN = fmax.FRADateID I get the same error "Conversion faile when converting datatime from character string)

Answer (score 1):

Try this: (ID is your primarykey from TblFire)

```
SELECT * FROM TblFire  t1
JOIN 
(
   SELECT ID, MAX(FRADate) AS FRADate
   FROM TblFire
   WHERE FRADate is not null 
   GROUP BY FRADate
) t2
ON T1.FRADate = t2.FRADate
AND t1.ID = t2.ID
```

Comment: Sadly the person who wrote it (not me) did not have an ID field.

Comment: There is no unique field but I can add one - just copying it from the server to my local PC now then I can play with the table.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's easier than it looks...

```
SELECT FireUPRN, Max(FRADate) as FRADate
FROM TblFire 
GROUP BY FireUPRN
```